# How can i do custom login with social security number and pass and not username or email?

Tags: django, django-authentication

Hallo all,

Using django 1.3 on python 2.6.5

I'm having a problem finding any help about this, I have a site that just has to (the client demands) authenticate the user login by socail security  number or passport number and not the regular fields.

I just can't find any thing about it...why do most of the tutorials are withouth any authentication or start with esumption that there is already and authentication system...

Can any one please explain it to me, how to i do the custom authentication, If could please show example or refere to page i would thank you a million times.. :-)

10x for all the help i am getting here, you guys are great :-)

Comment: OK, 10x John, mabye i will me more agresive about it... I thought about it, and as i am only the site developer i can't do any thing about it eventualy, but i think the same as you.... But you know, eventualy, i do what i am asked to do, i don't brake the law by doing that....so we will see what happen :-)

Comment: John, thank you again, i managed to convince the client to drop it and use email+password, saying "A veteran programmer i talked with told me is a very bad idea" really helped because he was relying on a "technical" friend of his that told him it is the best way, and when i started showing him other opinions it started to get irrelevant and started listening to me.... Customers...can't live with them can't pay rent without them...LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole topic in the django documentation about [custom authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

> An authentication backend is a class
>   that implements two methods:
>   get_user(user_id) and
>   authenticate(**credentials).

Comment: Hi and 10x, i read it, but how do i intergrate the UserProfile in that, it is talking only about the user fields (like any other tutorial) i need custom with UserProfile fields, or didn't i understand the article and get_it will do the trick? just can't get it yet...

Comment: If you are using AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE, you can use `user.get_profile().ssn` to access the ssn value. (I am assuming you are storing ssn in User Profile).

Comment: I know you all are raelly trying to help, but all the thnigs untill now are things that are obvios to me, sorry, what i can't understand that how to i do the authentication with a filed from the UserProfile modul....if you will look at the doc, they always do it with fields that are the the auth.User modum.....that is what i dont get.... 10x

Comment: You can extend the User model with other fields or using a custom UserProfile.

Comment: I already have it...every thing is set guys...i have a UserProfie, I read the docs, I know how to do authentication the regular way, jsut need to know how to do it (from someone that actualy did it before) with a fields that is not username or email....) all the rest i know, 10x for the help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You simple overwrite the django auth and write your own:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends